# Integrating jquery ui accordion collapsible

Tags: jquery-ui, accordion

I have a jquery-ui **accordion** widget with the setting `collapsible:true`. I want other elements on the page to slide up and down dynamically according to the height of the accordion widget. Also the accordion is inside a tabs widget. I would like the tab to expand to accommodate the height of the accordion.

I made a jsfiddle here to show my interface: [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/eierfiddle/aGvyw/0/)

Is there some way to have the text in red slide down when the accordion is opened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just give

```
#accordion{
display:inline;
}
```